# UniswapV2Pair, mint function, how is liquidity is created proportion to pair liquidity added

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, uniswap

```
function mint(address to) external lock returns (uint liquidity) {
   
}
```

The function above is implemented such that liquidity is added to the to address, however the liquidity is just minted depending on the difference of reserves and balance of token how will it create the liquidity in proportion to liquidity added by sender,

Am i missing something, what if a user always calls the mint function will he not get free LP token added to the address as we can see that the mint function is external not internal

Answer (score 0):

> Am i missing something, what if a user always calls the mint function will he not get free LP token added to the address as we can see that the mint function is external not internal

You are missing the function body and all the logic and checks inside it.

Comment: Hi @Mikko Thanks for taking out sometime and responding, I understood the logic, but as Petr said LP will mint to zero thats the main catch, I feel there is a vulnerability but need to see if thats possible

Comment: It's easily verifiable, Uniswap has been live for 2 years and processed billions of dollars. If there were such a vulnerability, it is unlikely it would not have been discovered.

Answer (score 0):

> *what if a user always calls the mint function will he not get free LP token added to the address*

The [mint()](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/v1.0.1/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol#L110) function itself only mints LP tokens to make up for a difference between actual LP balance and expected LP balance. If there's no difference between the actual and expected balances, no LP tokens are minted.

A common practice is to use the router function [addLiquidity()](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L61) which sends tokens to the Pair contract, and then invokes the `mint()` function - both as part of one transaction, so there's no way to frontrun this action.

If there were underlying tokens sent to the Pair contract without invoking the `mint()` function, then anyone could invoke this function freely claiming LP tokens representing this difference. However only once, as the LP mint zeros up the difference.

Comment: Petr thanks for the explanation, thats where I see a problem, what if I try to make calls to mint() directly continuously, there could be a front running situation created, someone who added ERC20 token to the pair and there will be a difference in the balance so the mint will give the tokens to the bot that called mint directly, so the actual investor might get zero tokens, I could be wrong if the way evm works in an atomic way meaning full complete function execution is done in one transaction, to my knowledge I don't think so function guarantees atomicity

Comment: @DinReddy You're right about the case of frontrunning the latter of two separate transactions. By the way, exactly this case is described in the famous [Ethereum is a Dark Forest](https://www.paradigm.xyz/2020/08/ethereum-is-a-dark-forest) article ... However, the EVM executes all transactions in series. So when both actions are executed as part of one "main" transaction executing `addLiquidity()`, there's no way for an attacker to squeeze anything in between them.

Comment: that was exactly I was looking for still there is a chance for frontrunning but very unlikely, theoretically possible when transfer instruction(tx) execution and mint instruction(tx) execution   are submitted in different blocks and our bot mint call is submitted on former block where transfer instruction is submitted and have to be called only after is in the same block, it's almost impossible.

Comment: @DinReddy If they're submitted as 2 separate transactions even in one block - then your assumption is correct... However, they can be both executed as internal transactions as part of one "main" transaction - and this makes it not possible to put any frontrunning transaction between them. The "main" transaction can execute the wrapping `addLiquidity()` function that I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> what if a user always calls the mint function will he not get free LP
> token added to the address as we can see that the mint function is
> external not internal

`mint()` is called when a user added liquidity.

> however the liquidity is just minted depending on the difference of
> reserves and balance of token how will it create the liquidity in
> proportion to liquidity added by sender,

Because the main equation is based on increasing liquidity is proportional to an increase in LP token shares. This makes sense because adding liquidity has no effect on price, so if you add more liquidity, you should receive LP tokens proportional to what you have received before

Let's say you have T shares and you want to increase liquidity from L0 to L1. How many more shares will be minted for you?

```
L1 / L0 = (T + mintAmount)/T
```

We need to find `mintAmount`.

```
(L1/L0) * T = T + mintAmount // leave mintAmount alone

((L1/L0)*T) - T = mintAmount // multiply T with L0/L0

((L1/L0)*T) - (T*L0)/L0 = mintAmount
```

Finally

```
mintAmount = ((L1-L0)/L0) * T
```